# How to decrease register Read/Write time consumption on a design with Microblaze?

Tags: fpga, microblaze

I'm using Microblaze Softcore Processor in many projects. I tried to measure the time consumption of writing to register and reading from register operations. Here are some results:

- Read two timer values and subtract them : **48 cycles**
- Read timer, read any register, read timer again and subtract timer values : **76 cycles**
- Read timer, write to any register, read timer again and subtract timer values : 83 cycles
- Read timer, read from any register, write to any register, read timer again and subtract values : **111 cycles**

I understood that a read operation takes nearly 28 cycles and one write operation takes nearly 35 cycles. **How can I decrease this cycles?**

By the way,
the configuration for the Microblaze is default. Nothing changed. No caches or shifters used. There are no boosted hardware in the design. AXI-Lite Bus used.

Comment: *"How can I decrease this cycles?"* Simply: you can't! You would have to redesign the whole Microblaze architecture which you don't have access to. If the timer is an external AXI peripheral you might shave off a cycle or two but I doubt that. If it would be that easy to reduce cycles, all processors would execute all instructions in one cycle, which they don't.

Comment: https://zipcpu.com/zipcpu/2019/02/09/cpu-blinky.html has some more discussion of the problem and possible solutions in a more general context.

Comment: @DavidShah That blog post looks like an advertisement of ZipCPU and couldn't solve my problem. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Oldfart I just wonder if I could make a better configuration for the Softcore. But, I see that from your answer, it is not really possible :/